# Sync S3 bucket to Google Drive

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, automation, google-drive-api, dropbox

I have an EC2 instance that collects data every night and syncs the collected data to an S3 bucket. I also have 5 teammates that have the same process going. So in total, we have 6 data sources, EC2 Instances, and buckets to scrape web data every night. We would like to combine all of our S3 buckets into one cloud storage space. We were thinking of using S3 but have run into issues with that so we are looking at Dropbox and GDrive as other options to sync our collected data every night. However, there does not seem to be a free (non-third-party) way to connect S3 to any other form of cloud storage.

Ideally, everything is able to run via the command line so that it stays automated and we can just add some more commands to our cron jobs. Does anyone have any advice on what cloud storage options to connect our S3's to, or how to connect our S3's to Dropbox or GDrive?

Answer (score 1):

If you are having problems using S3, I personally would try to figure out what those issues are and then resolve them - instead of adding in a new cloud service to the mix. Just adding a new vendor/platform into the mix, seems like a less than ideal way to solve what is probably just a problem understanding how to maximize the use of what you already have in place, and unnecessarily complicates things.

Comment: The issue we are having is we have student accounts so no canonical id. So we cannot link up our accounts to 1 S3, hence the reason for us all having individual S3’s and hopefully linking to GDrive or some other cloud storage